# In Javascript, why does array.map(String) return array of strings?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The list processing routine `map` on an array object is very convenient at times. Here's one of the handy ways to use it:

```
var numarr = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(numarr.map(String))

>>> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

I took this for granted thus far. Today I was however puzzled by it. What the `map` function is returning above is an array of strings. We typically pass a function to `map` as argument. In above case we pass `String` object. `String` is implemented inside the Javascript implementation, so I don't know what kind of specialities it has. The above code works as if a `new` instance of `String` is created for each item in array.

If it's not clear, consider this. If I decide to implement an object in Javascript say `MyString` and pass it to `map`, I won't get the above behavior.

```
function MyString(x) { this.val = x; }

MyString.prototype.toString = function () { return String(this.val); };

var ms = new MyString(4)

console.log(String(ms));
>>> "4"

var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.map(MyString)
>>> [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Does anyone know why then arr.map(String) works the way it does?

Update: [A comment I added below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329393/in-javascript-why-does-array-mapstring-return-array-of-strings#comment23403334_16329420) clarifies my question better.

Comment: Did you see what `typeof String` returns? *"If I decide to implement an object in Javascript say `MyString` [...]"*: `MyString` is a function too! But it shows `undefined` because you are not returning anything form it.

Comment: You are right, I am not returning anything. But then what should I return? a new instance of `MyString`?

Comment: To important point here is that while `String` is a construtor function which returns a string *object* when it is called with `new`, it returns a string *primitive value* when it's called *without* `new`. You can do something similar with your function if you wanted to. But in general this would not make sense for custom constructors, so you would rather use `.map` with `arr.map(function(v) { return new MyString(v); });`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the 2nd snippet, try `console.log(val)`. You'll notice you've leaked a global:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.map(MyString);
console.log(val); // "3"
```

When using `arr.map(MyString)`, you're calling that constructor as a function, without the `new` to create instances. And, since `MyString` doesn't `return` anything, you get `undefined` in the results. But, you've still set `this.val`, while `this` isn't an instance but is rather the *global object*.

`String` doesn't return `undefined` because it has a `return` when [called without `new`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.1):

> When String is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.

> Returns a String value (not a String object) computed by `ToString(value)`. If value is not supplied, the empty String `""` is returned.

You can imitate this with `MyString` by checking if `this` is an instance first, returning a new instance when `this` isn't one already:

```
function MyString(x) {
    if (this instanceof MyString) {
        this.val = x;
    } else {
        return new MyString(x);
    }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.map(MyString); // [ {val: "1"}, {val: "2"}, {val: "3"} ]
```

Comment: Good observation regarding leaked "val". Took me a while to understand . But the answer doesn't address the question I have. See the update I added. I'm not looking for a practical solution, just trying to understand Javascript better.

Comment: @Jayesh Regarding [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16329393/#comment23403334_16329420), you can avoid infinite recursion with `if (this instanceof ...)`. With it, you can either modify `this` when it is an instance or `return new MyString(x)` when it isn't. It should only recurse once if needed. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 4):

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array whose elements are the value returned by applying the specified function to each value in the `this` array. [`String` is a function; it returns a string.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) That's all there is to it.

Comment: Functions are always first-class Javascript objects: a function is a function object. You can also run the same trick on the other javascript "types": Array, Date, Number, Boolean, Object.

Comment: @thefrontender: What's your point? (as comment to this answer)

Comment: @FelixKling This was the best answer when I commented. Questioner is obviously confused about relationship between objects and functions in JS. Do you think this comment belongs elsewhere or is unhelpful?

Comment: @thefrontender: I thought you were criticizing this answer somehow, but couldn't see why. Now I understand that it is just additional information. It *might* have been better as comment to the question, but it's not a big deal, I was just confused.

Comment: Ok, I understand that "String is a function; it returns a string". Is it possible then to do it in pure javascript? If we write a Javascript object (i.e. function) and in its constructor create a new instance of itself in order to return it, won't it lead to infinite recursion? (This is out of mere curiosity about Javascript's working and not necessarily to solve a specific problem)

Comment: That example _is_ pure JavaScript. Yes, what you ask is possible; [Jonathan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16329487/139010) describes one way.

Answer (score 0):

Thats is because `String` *is* a function. It returns a string constructed from what is passed to it. For example, if you call `String(100)`, it will return `"100"`.